# Overwrite obsolete solution in tfs dev branch with solution in tfs main branch

Tags: version-control, tfs, merge, branch

In TFS 2013 how can I overwrite all folders and files under a specific folder with data from another branch?

I have a main and two dev branches and different functionality has been added to the same solution in both dev branches. Main is in sync with one dev branch. Now all functionality that has been added to the dev branch which is not in sync is now obsolete and I want to sync the solution in this branch with whats in main. As the solution differs alot between main and the obsolete branch a traditional merge wont work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just delete the branch (or rename it for archive purposes), and create a new branch off MAIN?

Another option is to rollback all changesets in the Obsolete-Dev branches history, then do a merge from MAIN.

Comment: I would go with the delete. Much cleaner.

Comment: The delete is not an option as there are other solutions in this branch that I want to keep but are out of sync. I went with doing a rollback and then merge which worked. Thanks